# Why is this LINQ IQueryable Performance for Pagination so poor?

Tags: c#, performance, linq, iqueryable

```
List<Device> deviceList = GetDevices(); // these are loaded in memory already as a list

IQueryable<Device> IDevices = deviceList.AsQueryable<Device>();

deviceList = IDevices.Where(i => i.StatusID == 2).OrderBy(j => j.LastCommunicated).Skip(recordsToSkip).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Given the above code, I have about 1000 devices in the list being queried on. The 3rd statement is very slow. Shouldn't it be fast if it is loaded into memory already? I understand in most scenarios you would apply the whole query to the database call, but in my case I already have my devices loaded in memory. The 1st and 2nd calls are very quick.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by very slow? Could you post your measurements? Even better, could you post the results of profiling the code?

Comment: That call should not be "very slow". Not with only 1000 items in that list. Are StatusID or LastCommunicated CPU intensive? Returning 4 iterators should not be an issue in and of itself. Take and skip are (according to my intuition and assembly knowledge) very fast operations.

Comment: @Dave, please do not rewrite your question to "I understand now."  That will help exactly 0 future users.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IQueryable` is irrelevant at that point. The performance issue you're seeing is that each chain returns a new iterator.

So, this:

```
IDevices
    .Where(i => i.StatusID == 2) // iterates over 1000 items
    .OrderBy(j => j.LastCommunicated) // orders however many items have a StatusID of 2
    .Skip(recordsToSkip) // iterates "recordsToSkip" number of times
    .Take(pageSize) // iterates "pageSize" times
```

Is a step by step process. First, `Where` executes. This iterates over the entire list. Then `OrderBy` executes, which as you can imagine is quite intensive. `Skip` then iterates through until it finds the index you want to be at. `Take` then iterates over *n* items before you form a new list.

That being said.. had you just run this query straight against the database, it would have been much quicker.

Comment: I see. I figured since the data was in memory already that I would be able to sort it quickly.

Comment: "each chain returns a new list" - this is not correct - each chain returns a new _iterator_.

Comment: @DStanley Apologies. Fixed.

Comment: You should probably consider fetching the data from db again, even if you already have whole table in memory. Ofc. If it's a db related case.

Comment: @Dave You'll never be able to write code that matches the speed of a database that has all sorts of indexing capabilities (unless you implement them yourself). This is especially true whilst using LINQ on in-memory collections.

Comment: Yes, I will hit the database again. This question should be deleted I suppose.

Comment: @Dave, not at all.  You've discovered an answer that satisfies you; this question (and answer) might help someone in the future who faces the same predicament.

Comment: This answer states that ```Where``` iterates over the whole sequence at first, seperately from ```OrderBy```. Isn't this wrong since each chain creates an iterator and each one iterates when the the former iterator forces to iterate? ```Where().OrderBy()``` doesn't iterate the sequence twice, they iterate as much as ```OrderBy``` requests at total. However ```OrderBy``` forces to iterate the whole sequence at once, so even if ```Skip(10).Take(10).ToList()``` is called after OrderBy, it iterates the whole sequence first and then 20 more items get iterated. Am i wrong? If not, the answer is.